# R - Select and return column value based on value in another column

Tags: r

I'd like to select and return a column value contained within one of a subset of columns, based on the value in another column.

Specifically, I'd like to create a new variable ("NEWE") by selecting the value in RE when the MAX variable = "RP" and by selecting the value in IE when the MAX variable = "IP".

Of note, I am working with a data table of ~160 columns and ~70,000 rows (I am noting the existence of additional columns in my example by including V1-V9).

Have:

```
V1  …   V9  RE  IE  MAX
4   …   3   3   4   RP  
6   …   6   3   2   IP  
2   …   2   1   2   IP  
6   …   2   2   3   RP  
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .
```

And the data set I would like:

```
V1  …   V9  RE  IE  MAX NEWE
4   …   3   3   4   RP  3
6   …   6   3   2   IP  2
2   …   2   1   2   IP  2
6   …   2   2   3   RP  2
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you try using `ifelse`?

Comment: will it be just between "RP" and "IP" always??

Comment: No, the procedure will be carried out in two iterations between six different columns

Comment: didn't get your point ..2 iterations? anyway hope my answer helps you in it

Comment: First, "MAX" value (of which there are six unique strings) will be used to choose the value from one of six columns:  when RP choose value in RE, when IP choose IE, when AP choose AE, when SP chose  SE, when EP choose EE, when CP chose  CE.  Then I need to do the same thing where "MAX" will be used to choose the value from one of six DIFFERENT columns (say RA, IA, AA, SA, EA, CA).  This would result in a second new variable added ("NEWA").  Could you extend to this more complete example?  Thanks for the help here!

Comment: And just to be sure, some "MAX" values are missing, so "NEWE" (and "NEWA", the resulting variable from the second iteration described above) should also report as missing in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data$NEWE <- ifelse(data$MAX == "RP", data$RE, ifelse(data$MAX == "RP",data$IE, "value if both doesn't satify"))
```

if its either of RP and IP always!

```
data$NEWE <- ifelse(data$MAX == "RP", data$RE , data$IE)
```

for your case : its a simple extension of ifelse - (to avoid typo prefer using with())

```
data$NEWE <- with(data, ifelse(MAX == "RP", RE,
                               ifelse(MAX == "IP",IE, 
                                     ifelse(MAX == "AP", AE,
                                           ifelse(MAX == "SP", SE,
                                                  ifelse(MAX == "EP",EE,
                                                         ifelse(MAX == "CP", CE, NA)))))))
```